# What is the right way to try to make a revision to an existing commit of a merged feature branch?

Tags: tortoisegit

I am still learning the features of using **TortoiseGit** and the concept of *version control*.

I have read the this [article](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-patch.html) and it is not clear to me if I need to follow that procedure. It describes **patching**.

So, I have this feature branch that has now been merged into the master as indicated. I want to have a go at making a revision to the application with respects to one of the commits (highlighted). So I would like to try out an idea to do things differently and implement it if I am happy.

[image: Log]

What is the correct way to do this? I am a sole developer and am not in collaboration with others for my project.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @MrTux I am about to make a refinement to the content of this feature branch. Do I just do a new commit at top of master or do I do a patch or something on the actual branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will always be times when you realize that a commit is not perfect or introduced an error.

You have several options:

1) Fix the issue and commit the fix on `master` (or in a bugfix/feature branch). You should do this, especially, if the "faulty" commit is some longer time ago.

2) Option 1 might have the disadvantage that you don't know that this fix belogs to a recent feature branch. Here, you could switch to the feature branch again (if you already deleted the branch, re-create it on the latest commit before the merge), commit the fix there and merge the feature branch again to `master`. This way you can see in the log that this fix also belongs to the feature branch.

3) The third option would be to rewrite your history - the is especially discouraged if you develop with other users and the "faulty" commit is already pushed or older. For rewriting history, go to the log dialog and open the context menu on the commit just before the faulty commit and select "Rebase ... onto this". Then the rebase dialog opens, check "Preserve merges" and "Force" there - then all commits starting with the "faulty" one should be displayed. Now, click on the "faulty" commit and mark it as "Edit" and then start the rebase. - Now your working tree is put back into that old state. Do your changes on the working tree, check "Edit/Split commit" and click on "Amend" on the rebase dialog. - After that all other remaining commits are re-applied and the fix is included in your history.

PS: The article about patches and pull requests is about sharing changes with other developers.

Comment: I used option 1 as a commit on the master. Option 2 does sound nice too so if I think I need to do that I will try to follow those instructions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sole developer and you are absolutely sure that no external party has checked out your master you can do the following:

- Create backup of your master branch by branching off from the top of current master.
- Looks like you also have changes committed to your master branch. Create a feature branch on from the master as well.  At this point master-backup branch and your new-branch should be identical
- Reset your master to the state before your merged in your feature branch. In this case this is 'Removed MWB files....'
- Checkout your feature branch you want to change
- Do `git rebase -i master`
- Edit the line that has your commit that you want to change.  Change 'pick' to 'e' and save the file to kick off interactive rebase
- When rebase stops at the commit you want to change  do `git reset HEAD~` this will put your working directory into the state before you did your commit. With all changes being on the index.
- Make necessary changes to your source and commit
- Do `git rebase continue`
- Once interactive rebase finishes. Checkout master and merge your new feature branch into int.
- Checkout your next branch 'lingala' translation.
- Rebase it on top of new master, and then merge
- Checkout your feature/new-branch, and rebase on top of new master then merge
- You done.  Push everything to your remote.  Note that you have to use 'git push --force'
- If you have code checkout on other machines,  make sure to do the following

  git fetch ;
  git checkout master ;
  git reset --hard origin/master
- Note the last step will destroy any local changes you have on your master branch and any uncommitted files.  If you want to preserve them either stash them or create a temp local branch that you can later rebase on top of new master

Comment: Thanks. Scratches head. I am going to have to digest all this. It sounds complicated for just a minor revision to the feature. I was hoping for a simpler working solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to preserve your history tree as is just do the following steps:

- Start interactive rebase `git rebase -i 'xxxxxxx'`  where `xxxxxx` is commit id of the commit with the comment 'Removed MWB files....'
- In your rebase sheet edit the line of the commit that you want to change by replacing 'pick' with 'edit'
- When rebase stops. Do 'git reset HEAD~'  this will put your working directory into the state that was right before you committed these changes.
- Make changes to your files, commit them.
- Do `git rebase --continue`
- Push your master branch with `--force` option
- PROFIT

**BEFORE YOU DO THIS.  MAKE SURE TO CREATE A BACKUP COPY OF YOUR MASTER BRANCH**

If something goes wrong you can restore master branch from the backup by doing

`git checkout master
  git reset --hard backup-master
  git push --force`

Comment: Thanks. I don't necessarily want to lose what I have as it would be nice to preserve the history. I will continue going through your answers to make a decision. If push comes to shove I will just add a fresh commit to the master branch for my tweak.